# Scala Circe with generics

Tags: json, scala, circe

I am trying to use the scala json library Circe, wrapping it in a simple trait to provide conversion to/from json for which I have the following:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._

trait JsonConverter {
  def toJson[T](t : T) : String
  def fromJson[T](s: String) : T
}

case class CirceJsonConverter() extends JsonConverter{
  override def toJson[T](t: T): String = t.asJson.noSpaces
  override def fromJson[T](s: String): T = decode[T](s).getOrElse(null).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

The aim of this is to simply be able to call JsonConverter with any object and have it convert it to/from json as such `jsonConverter.toJson(0) must equalTo("0")` , however when I try to compile it I get the following:

```
[error] could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[T]
[error]   override def toJson[T](t: T): String = t.asJson.noSpaces
[error]                                            ^
[error] could not find implicit value for parameter decoder: io.circe.Decoder[T]
[error]   override def fromJson[T](s: String): T = decode[T](s).getOrElse(null).asInstanceOf[T]
[error]                                                     ^
[error] two errors found
```

I can of course have a class that everything I intend to put through the converter inherit from, but I had the impression that circe could auto generate the encoders/decoders?

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75627162/21293767 using generics with case class MyClass[T] might help:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is not going to work unless you can implement a strategy for turning any object into Json... which seems unlikely. Circe (and many other libs) instead choose to use a common pattern called Type Classes to make it convenient to define how you want to do something, in this case `Encoder`/`Decoder`, for a *specific type*.

I recommend researching Type Classes if you are unfamiliar with them. And then take a look at the Circe docs to see how you can implement Encoders/Decoders specifically.

Comment: For the record, the import of io.circe.generic.auto._ is a convenient way of producing instances but it doesn't magically make instances for anything and everything. It only makes them for case classes defined in the file with that import.

Comment: one nice  alternative for `import io.circe.generic.auto._` then is `import io.circe.generic.semiauto._` (which I prefer) and then explicitly once by type: `lazy implicit val e01: Encoder[MyType] = deriveEncoder` and `lazy implicit val d01: Decoder[MyType] = deriveDecoder`

Answer (score 4):

Following Idan Waisman answer and C4stor [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41063653/746347) in my duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41058947/746347) I used the Type Classes pattern. For brevity I provide sample code only for decoding json. Encoding can be implemented in exactly the same way.

First, let's define the trait that will be used to inject json decoder dependency:

```
trait JsonDecoder[T] {
  def apply(s: String): Option[T]
}
```

Next we define object that creates instance implementing this trait:

```
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.parser.decode

object CirceDecoderProvider {
  def apply[T: Decoder]: JsonDecoder[T] =
    new JsonDecoder[T] {
      def apply(s: String) =
        decode[T](s).fold(_ => None, s => Some(s))
    }
}
```

As you can notice `apply` requires implicit `io.circe.Decoder[T]` to be in scope when it called.

Then we copy `io.circe.generic.auto` object content and create a trait (I made [PR](https://github.com/circe/circe/pull/504) to have this trait available as `io.circe.generic.Auto`):

```
import io.circe.export.Exported
import io.circe.generic.decoding.DerivedDecoder
import io.circe.generic.encoding.DerivedObjectEncoder
import io.circe.{ Decoder, ObjectEncoder }
import io.circe.generic.util.macros.ExportMacros
import scala.language.experimental.macros

trait Auto {
  implicit def exportDecoder[A]: Exported[Decoder[A]] = macro ExportMacros.exportDecoder[DerivedDecoder, A]
  implicit def exportEncoder[A]: Exported[ObjectEncoder[A]] = macro ExportMacros.exportEncoder[DerivedObjectEncoder, A]
}
```

Next in the package (e.g. `com.example.app.json`) that uses json decoding a lot we create package object if does not exist and make it extend `Auto` trait and provide implicit returning `JsonDecoder[T]` for given type `T`:

```
package com.example.app

import io.circe.Decoder

package object json extends Auto {
    implicit def decoder[T: Decoder]: JsonDecoder[T] = CirceDecoderProvider[T]
}
```

Now:

- all source files in `com.example.app.json` has `Auto` implicits in scope
- you can get `JsonDecoder[T]` for any type `T` that has `io.circe.Decoder[T]` or for which it can be generated with `Auto` implicits
- you do not need to import `io.circe.generic.auto._` in every file
- you can switch between json libraries by only changing `com.example.app.json` package object content.

For example you can switch to [json4s](http://json4s.org) (though I did the opposite and switched to circe from json4s). Implement provider for `JsonDecoder[T]`:

```
import org.json4s.Formats
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

import scala.util.Try

case class Json4SDecoderProvider(formats: Formats) {
  def apply[T: Manifest]: JsonDecoder[T] =
    new JsonDecoder[T] {
      def apply(s: String) = {
        implicit val f = formats
        Try(parse(s).extract[T]).toOption
      }
    }
}
```

And change `com.example.app.json` package object content to:

```
package com.example.app

import org.json4s.DefaultFormats

package object json {
    implicit def decoder[T: Manifest]: JsonDecoder[T] = Json4SDecoderProvider(DefaultFormats)[T]
}
```

With Type Classes pattern you get compile-time dependency injection. That gives you less flexibility than runtime dependency injection but I doubt that you need to switch json parsers in runtime.