# Generic json decoder trait with Circe implementation

Tags: scala, circe

I have a trait used to inject json decoder as dependency to components of my project:

```
trait JsonDecoder {
  def apply[T](s: String): Option[T]
}
```

When I try to implement it with [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/):

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser.decode

case class CirceJsonDecoder() extends JsonDecoder {
  def apply[T](s: String): Option[T] = {
    decode[T](s).fold(_ => None, s => Some(s)) 
  }
}
```

and run:

```
case class C()

def test(d: JsonDecoder) = d[C]("{}")

test(CirceJsonDecoder())
```

it does not compile with error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter decoder: io.circe.Decoder[T]
```

I tried to add `ClassTag`, `TypeTag` or `WeakTypeTag` context bounds for `T` but it still can not find implicit value for `Decoder`.

I can not add `Decoder` context bound or implicit parameter to `JsonDecoder.apply` because components what use it should not know about implementation details.

How should I provide implicit `io.circe.Decoder`? May be there is some way to get it from `TypeTag`?

Comment: From what I understand how you tried to fix it (adding reflection via `ClassTag`/`TypeTag`), you assume circe uses reflection to derive the json codecs. That's not the case. Instead, circe derives the codecs at compiletime, so it needs more information than just `T` about a type. You could try `shapeless.LabelledGeneric` or `shapless.Generic` context bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can without affecting your apply method signature in any way involving circe.
If you could, it'd mean `circe.auto_` is capable of bringing an implicit decoder in scope for any type T, which is not true.

AFAIK, there's no better type annotation than adding an implicit `Decoder` to your function to signal circe that it actually knows how to handle this type (if you prefer, you can use the `T: Decoder` version, but it's the same in the end).

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted your answer but I found the same question asked before and marked this as duplicate. I'll post my final solution there. I uses the type class approach as you and the guy from that question suggested.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41102192/746347.