# Define generic decoder in scala using circe

Tags: scala, generics, circe

I'm trying to switch my JsonUtils class from Json4s to circe
and i find it hard to solve the generic implementation for the decoder.

my Json4s func look like this:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  def extractValueFromJson[T](json: String, key: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
    val parsed = parse(json).asInstanceOf[JObject]
    val value =(parsed \ key).extract[T]
    value
  }
```

example of usage:

```
extractValueFromJson[String](jsonStr, keyInJson)
```

and it is working perfectly

now i have tried the same func with circe:

```
 implicit def decodeGeneric[A: Decoder](json: Json): Either[Error, A] = Decoder[A].decodeJson(json)
    def extractValueFromJson[A: ClassTag, T](jsonStr: String, key: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
            val json: String = jsonStr.asJson.noSpaces
            decode[A](json) match {
              case Left(error: Error) => throw error
              case Right(value) => {
                value.getClass.getDeclaredField(key).get(value).asInstanceOf[T] 
              }
            }
          }
```

and i get the following error while compiling:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type io.circe.Decoder[A]
[error]         decode[A](json) match {
[error]                  ^
```

This is the desired output for a given input 
input:

```
case class Bar(str: String)
val bar = Bar("just a string")
```

usage:

```
val test = extractValueFromJson[Bar,String](bar.asJson.noSpaces,"str")
```

output:

```
just a string
```

What am i doing wrong here? 
Is there a way to define a generic decoder?
i have read some similar questions here but haven't found a solution that fit my needs

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it gives me the error i have enclosed above as i said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def extractValueFromJson[A](jsonStr: String, key: String)(implicit decoder: Decoder[A]): A =
  io.circe.parser.decode(jsonStr)(decoder.at(field = key)) match {
    case Right(result) => result
    case Left(error) => throw error
  }
```

Which you can use like this:

```
extractValueFromJson[String](jsonStr = bar.asJson.noSpaces, key = "str")
// res: String = "just a string"
```

Comment: i get the following error for this try 
Exception in thread "main" DecodingFailure(Attempt to decode value on failed cursor, List(DownField(xs)))

Comment: @soosita can you please edit your question with the sample input and the expected output.

Comment: i have added the example of usage

Comment: @soosita look at the edited answer, the code had a little typo _(sorry about that)_ and you were using it wrong _(due my typo)_.

Answer (score 0):

This answer [Circe encoder for generic case class with default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400343/circe-encoder-for-generic-case-class-with-default-parameters/75627162#75627162) using generics with case class MyClass[T] might help:

```
case class JsonParserCirce[T](implicit val lazyDecoder: Lazy[DerivedDecoder[T]]) {
  implicit val coderLocale: Coder[Locale] = Coder.kryo[Locale]
  implicit def defaultDecoder: Decoder[T] = deriveDecoder[T]

  def parseJSONStrings(
    messages: SCollection[String]
  )(implicit coder: Coder[T]): (SCollection[T], SCollection[JsonError]) = {
    log.info("Parsing JSON Strings...")
    val jsons: SCollection[Either[circe.Error, T]] = messages.map { s: String => json2CaseClass(s) }

/*My Transformations*/

// String to Json using Circe
  def json2CaseClass(jsonStr: String): Either[circe.Error, T] =
    decode(jsonStr)
```